# Animating a single element by clicking within a list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying and trying to find out a way to animate a single element within an angular generated list when I click it. I have tried some of the solution here and there on Google.

```html
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" [@listAnimation]="logAnimation()">
    <div>{{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code will animate once the list is loading, but not when I click on the element after it is loaded.

The other way is to store the state of html element in the data and then see against it if the state is changed, but that is difficult once the data is loading dynamically from the server.
I did not find anything else.
I tried the solution mentioned in my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74685461/why-set-html-element-state-in-data-object-in-typescript-angular) question. This solution is mixing data and the html element. I want to know if there is any other solution beside this?

```
export const listAnimation = trigger('listAnimation',
[
 state('before', style({
 opacity: .5
 })),
    transition('before <=> after', animate(1000)),
])
export class SubjectcontentComponent implements OnInit {
selectedItem:any;
subjects= [
{ id: 12, name: 'PHP', state:'before ' },
{ id: 13, name: 'Javascript' , state:'before '  },
{ id: 14, name: 'Css', state:'before '  },
{ id: 15, name: 'Angular' , state:'before '  },
{ id: 16, name: 'Laravel' , state:'before ' },
{ id: 17, name: 'java', state:'before ' },
{ id: 18, name: 'asp' , state:'before ' },
{ id: 19, name: 'python' , state:'before ' },
{ id: 20, name: 'database'  , state:'before ' }
];
 state: string='small';
i=0;
constructor( private subjectcontentService: 
SubjectcontentsService 
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.subjects=this.subjects.map((subject)=> {
subject.state='before';
return subject;
})
}
toggle(subject:any){
if(subject.state=='before')
{
 subject.state='after';
}
else{
 subject.state='before';
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation is triggered when the state of `listAnimation` in your case changes but in your case there is no click event that can change a state.

Try this as an example:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" @listAnimation (click)="listAnimation === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on'">
    <div (click)="listAnimation === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on'">{{ item }}</div >
  </div>
</div>
```

In your component define you animations:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  animations: [
    trigger('listAnimation', [
      state('on', style({
        opacity: 1
      })),
      state('off', style({
        opacity: 0.5,
      })),
      transition('on => off', [
        animate('1s')
      ]),
      transition('off => on', [
        animate('0.5s')
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
  (...)
})
```

In this case when you click your element then the animation state will toggle `on` / `off` and it will change it's opacity styling.

For more refer to [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/animations)

Comment: it is not working on my side, and beside, what if I want to use the click event for some other task?

Comment: should I declare the listAnimation as property on component class first?

Comment: dear, I think you did not read my question properly. I have mentioned the click event and how it changes the property associated with each row of data. the method you mentioned will again change the state of all the rows at once, if it ever worked.